# wx Module misses attribute ArtProvider

Tags: python, wxpython, sumo

I am adapting a model in SUMO and try to run a file (sumopy_gui.py).
When doing so I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: module 'wx' has no attribute 'ArtProvider_GetBitmap'

I tried to update wx in the cmd line, reinstalling it, but I don't find a reason why wx shouldn't have this module. All the other modules seem to be working for now.
Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Probably [supposed to be](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ArtProvider.html#wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap) `ArtProvider.GetBitmap`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wxPython 4, then you want to use `wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap`. Previous versions (i.e. Classic) used the old `ArtProvider_GetBitmap`.

A good place to check for these kinds of differences is the following:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html

I also recommend reading the Migration Guide from Classic to Phoenix:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html